# CSS different when loaded inside a iframe

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a very basic html preview editor
When below html is typed in and preview button is clicked, the font-fmaily of css isnt loading in iframe

The expected output is
[image]

But my iframe shows as
[image]

Which means the font isnt loading properly in my iframe

This is the code that you need to paste in below editor

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/css/add-ons1.css">
<body style="height: auto; overflow: hidden; padding: 16px; --devsite-panel-height:0px;" ready="">
    <meta name="suppress_site_styles" content="true"><meta name="auto_height" content="true"><meta name="auto_width" content="true">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/css/add-ons1.css">
      <h1>Titles and headers</h1>
      <b>Bold text</b><br>
      Normal text<br>
      <a href="">Links</a><br>
      <span class="current">Current navigation selection</span><br>
      <span class="error">Form input errors</span><br>
      <span class="gray">Gray text</span><br>
      <span class="secondary">Secondary text</span><br>
      
  
</body>
```

**PLEASE NOTE, THIS IFRAME WILL NOT SHOW IN STACKOVERFLOW SNIPPET EDITOR, YOU NEED TO DOWNLOAD THIS CODE TO YOUR SYSTEM**

```html
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/somethinggoodone/cdn/AniketPradhan_bootstrap.css" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-kenU1KFdBIe4zVF0s0G1M5b4hcpxyD9F7jL+jjXkk+Q2h455rYXK/7HAuoJl+0I4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<head>
    <style>
    .stool {
        cursor: pointer;
        user-select: none;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        z-index: 999;

    }
    </style>
</head>

<body class="p-3">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div class="container position-relative border">
        <div class="toolbar mt-3">
            <small id="showpreview" class="bg-light border border-secondary stool position-absolute top-0 end-0 px-2">
                Preview
            </small>
            <small id="showhtml" class="bg-light border border-secondary stool position-absolute top-0 end-0 px-2" style="display:none">
                HTML
            </small>
        </div>
        <div>
            <textarea id="embody" class="m-0 p-0 border-0 mt-2" style="width:100%;resize: none;outline: none">&lt;h3&gt;Compose your email body text.&lt;/h3&gt;</textarea>

            <iframe src="javascript:void(0);" id="embody-preview" style="width:100%;">

            </iframe>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $("#showpreview").click(function() {
        $(this).hide();
        $("#embody-preview").contents().find('html').html(embody.value)
        $("#showhtml,#embody-preview").show();
        $("#embody").hide();
    });
    $("#showhtml").click(function() {
        $(this).hide();
        $("#showpreview,#embody").show();
        $("#embody-preview").hide();
    });    
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Populate the iframes `body` instead of the `html` root:

```
$("#showpreview").click(function () {
  $(this).hide();
  $("#embody-preview").contents().find("body").html(embody.value);
  $("#showhtml,#embody-preview").show();
  $("#embody").hide();
});
```

Otherwise it might be easier to append a general editor stylesheet to you iframe like so:

```
let iframe = document.getElementById("embody-preview");
let doc = iframe.contentDocument;
let style = doc.createElement("style");
let link = doc.createElement("link");
link.rel = "stylesheet";
link.href = "https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/css/add-ons1.css";
style.textContent = `
body{
font-family:sans-serif;
color:red!important;
}
`;
doc.head.appendChild(link);
doc.head.appendChild(style);
```

[Codepen Example](https://codepen.io/herrstrietzel/pen/RwBKMyR)